# GeoServer labels & vendor options

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have the following label style defined in geoserver SLD stylesheet:

```
<TextSymbolizer>
        <Label>
          <ogc:PropertyName>pisanjeimena</ogc:PropertyName>
        </Label>
        <VendorOption name="group">false</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="labelAllGroup">true</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="spaceAround">20</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="goodnessOfFit">0</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">10</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="autoWrap">150</VendorOption>           
        <Halo>
          <Radius>2</Radius>
          <Fill>
            <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.6</CssParameter>
          </Fill>
        </Halo>
        <Font>
          <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.6</CssParameter>
        </Font>
        <LabelPlacement>
          <PointPlacement>
            <AnchorPoint>
              <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
              <AnchorPointY>0.0</AnchorPointY>
            </AnchorPoint>
            <Displacement>
              <DisplacementX>0</DisplacementX>
              <DisplacementY>5</DisplacementY>
            </Displacement>
          </PointPlacement>
        </LabelPlacement>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill"><ogc:PropertyName>boja</ogc:PropertyName></CssParameter>
        </Fill>             
      </TextSymbolizer>
```

The style is defined for point layer.

Can someone explain what do vendor opetions "group" and "labelAllGroup" do together in this case?

I'm asking because  is set to false. Does this mean that  will also not be applied?

According to documentation, labelAllGroup causes all of the disjoint paths in a line group to be labeled, not just the longest one. How will this work if layer contains only points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without access to the data set it is hard to say exactly what will happen, you can experiment by deleting one or both of the lines and looking to see what the difference is.

From looking at the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#labelallgroup) I would think that `labelAllGroup` has no effect when `group` is set to false. If `group` and `labelAllGroup` were both true for a point layer I would expect all the points in the group to be labeled, i.e. the same as with neither set.